# The LINQ expression could not be translated System.Version.Parse

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.version

I am using EF and I'm trying to query some records which have a version column like this:

```
var servicesWhichExistInDifferentDataCenters = dbContext.CurrentRunningServices
    .Where(r => r.DeployedRing == ring 
        && r.DataCenter == defaultDataCenterIndex 
        && r.IsActive)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => dbContext.CurrentRunningServices
        .Any(r2 => r2.DeployedRing == r.DeployedRing 
          && r2.DockerImageName == r.DockerImageName 
          && r2.DataCenter != r.DataCenter 
          && Version.Parse(r2.DeploymentVersion) != Version.Parse(r.DeploymentVersion)))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToList();
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Any(c => c.DeployedRing == __r_DeployedRing_0 && c.DockerImageName == __r_DockerImageName_1 && c.DataCenter != __r_DataCenter_2 && Version.Parse(c.DeploymentVersion) != __Parse_3)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Version.Parse' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The query runs fine locally in VS, but I get the above error when running it on the server, even though the server is just running an image prepared from the local code. Why is it happening?

Comment: Do you actually need to parse the versions? What situation are you expecting where a simpler comparison wouldn't behave as you want it to?

Comment: Well it started with Parse since at first I had to check if the version is smaller and not just different. If now I only need to check that it's different then I actually can just not use Version.Parse?

Comment: You're in a better position to answer that than I am. I don't know whether there are any odd cases you need to consider such as "1.0" and "1.00" both being in the database. But I'd at least try it...

Comment: All versions are SemVer

Comment: Okay, then I *believe* you should be fine to just compare the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Version.Parse(r2.DeploymentVersion) != Version.Parse(r.DeploymentVersion)`

This comparison cannot be "translated" to SQL and run on the server.

You can either insert *another* `.AsEnumerable()` here:

```
dbContext.CurrentRunningServices.AsEnumerable().Any
```

which would drag *all* the data and processing over to the client.

**OR**

You could just skip the version parsing and compare the strings on the database server, which would enable you to remove all your `.AsEnumerable()`s, that I guess are only in there to debug/guess a solution to your problem.

If your version field is not normalized, then normalize it before putting it into the database, not on each comparison again and again.

---

As for why this is not happening if you run it locally, I can only offer an educated guess: maybe you are not running a real SQL server locally, but an in-memory database of sorts? Many of those use shortcuts and do not actually translate your statement to SQL.

Comment: I removed the Version.Parse and all AsEnumerable and it worked